# How to determine the probability that two variables are related?

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a set of observations. Each observation has two variables:

```
# | VarA  | VarB
--|-------|-------
1 | True  | False
2 | False | False
3 | True  | True
4 | True  | False
...
(143,804 rows)
```

From this, I've got the following table:

```
          | VarB true | VarB false
VarA true |   729     |    1296
VarA false|   1753    |   140026
```

I want to know the chance that VarA and VarB are related, in the sense that their likelihood of occurring together is significantly higher than suggested by chance.

It's rare that an observation contains VarA or VarB (1.98% and 1.41% respectively); if the variables were randomly distributed I'd expect to see (0.0198*0.0141)*143804 = 40 co-occurrences, but instead I see 729.

My question is: for this and other observations, what test(s) can I run to check whether the results are independent or related? I've looked at chi-squared, but I can't work out whether it's valid.

Comment: You are asking the wrong question.  In classical statistics there is no such thing as "the probability that VarA and VarB are related".  What a statistical test might give you is an estimate for the probability of getting $729$ or more co-occurrences given that they are **independent**.

Comment: A chi-squared test is appropriate here and not surprisingly will reject a null hypothesis that the two variables are independent, essentially for the reason you give (you have your percentages slightly  wrong)

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thank you, that is a helpful way to think about it.

Comment: @Henry I'm not sure if I'm applying the chi-squared test appropriately. I used [this online calculator](https://graphpad.com/quickcalcs/contingency1/) using "Chi-square with Yates' correction" and dividing my values by ten, since they were too high for the calculator. Top row: 73,130. Bottom row: 175,14003. Is that correct?

Comment: Dividing all the values by about $10$ will divide the resulting $\chi^2$ value by about $10$ reducing the significance of the result.  In this case it is still highly significant, though in others it might change the conclusion

Comment: @Henry I don't know if you want to submit this as an answer but I'd accept it if you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*As requested in comments:*

A chi-squared test is appropriate here (a large sample makes Fisher's exact test unnecessary) and not surprisingly will reject a null hypothesis that the two variables are independent, essentially for the reason you give (you have your percentages slightly wrong)

Dividing all the values by about $10$ as you tried for your linked calculator 
will divide the resulting $\chi^2$ value by about $10$ reducing the significance of the result. In this case it is still highly significant, though in others it might change the conclusion

In R you could see something like

```
> contingencytable = matrix(c(729, 1296, 1753, 140026), ncol=2)
> chisq.test(contingencytable)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction

data:  contingencytable
X-squared = 14204, df = 1, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

Answer (score 0):

In general terms, if you have two random variables $A$ and $B$ and you have the joint probability distribution $P(A,B)$, then by marginalization you can find out if they are independent, i.e., $P(A,B) = P(A) P(B)$.
Marginalization means $P(A) = \sum_b P(A,b)$ and $P(B) =\sum_a P(a,B)$.